# Cannot find spring 4 maven artifact

Tags: java, spring, maven, repository, nexus

According to the springio documentation [here](http://projects.spring.io/spring-framework/#quick-start) I should be able to just cut and paste this...

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-framework</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.5.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

...into my maven pom, which I did, but it fails to resolve the version.

So I looked and found [this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/Spring-repository-FAQ#for-the-impatient) and I added a proxy repository to my nexus for the [release] (http://repo.spring.io/release) repository but still failed to locate the artifact.

Then I navigated to the http://repo.spring.io/release repo and manually searched and CANNOT FIND the  artifact.

So, where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a mistake in the guide.
Somewhere below it mentions "spring-context", so I believe that should have been:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Notice "spring-context" instead of "spring-framework".
Github issue to have that fixed: [Github issue](https://github.com/spring-guides/getting-started-guides/issues/6).